# When in a protected sheet in macro, if I delete an unblocked cell, the sheet would become unprotected

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a protected sheet, where I run a macro. Since macros don't run on protected sheets, the first thing i did was to unprotect the sheet from the VBA, and after the macro runs, it will protect it again.

The code basically let's you choose something from a dropdown list in a cell, let's say cell A1, and it affects other cells that also have a dropdown list. So when you choose something on A1, the other cells with the dropdown will be blank, and it will let you choose something from the dropdown. If you choose something else on A1, the other cells will turn blank again, and the process keeps repeating.

But the problem is, if I press the Delete button on one of the dropdown list cells, the sheet will become unprotected. I need this sheet to always be protected, even if i delete one of those cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "test"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim str_line As Integer: str_line = 57
Dim fin_line As Integer: fin_line = 1056
Dim variante As Variant


For i = str_line To fin_line
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AM" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("AM" & i)
            Case "scenario 1":
                Cells(i, 41) = ""

                Cells(i, 44) = ""
                
            Case "":
                Cells(i, 41) = ""

                Cells(i, 44) = ""
        End Select
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("G" & i)
            Case "Review":
                    Cells(i, 39) = ""
                    Cells(i, 41) = ""
                    Cells(i, 44) = ""

        End Select
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("D" & i)
            Case "Full":
                Cells(i, 5) = ""

            Case "Quota":
                Cells(i, 5) = ""
        End Select
    End If
Next i

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L17")) Is Nothing Then
            Select Case Range("L17")
                Case "yes":
                    Sheets("Materiality Allocation").Columns("I:I").Hidden = False
                    Sheets("Materiality Allocation").Columns("H:H").Hidden = False
                Case "no":
                    Sheets("Materiality Allocation").Columns("I:I").Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Materiality Allocation").Columns("H:H").Hidden = True
                    For i = str_line To fin_line
                        If Cells(i, 8) <> "n/a" Then
                            Cells(i, 8) = "n/a"
                        End If
                    Next i
                    Range("I57:I1056").value = ""
                    
                Case "n/a":
                    Sheets("Materiality Allocation").Columns("I:I").Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Materiality Allocation").Columns("H:H").Hidden = True
                    Range("I57:I1056").value = ""
                    For i = str_line To fin_line
                        If Cells(i, 8) <> "n/a" Then
                            Cells(i, 8) = "n/a"
                        End If
                    Next i
                Case "":
                    Sheets("Materiality Allocation").Columns("I:I").Hidden = True
                    Sheets("Materiality Allocation").Columns("H:H").Hidden = True
                    Range("I57:I1056").value = ""
                    For i = str_line To fin_line
                        If Cells(i, 8) <> "n/a" Then
                            Cells(i, 8) = "n/a"
                        End If
                    Next i
            
            End Select
    End If



For i = str_line To fin_line
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H" & i)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("H" & i)
            Case "no":
                    Cells(i, 9) = ""

            Case "n/a":
                    Cells(i, 9) = ""
        End Select
    End If
Next i

        


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("nb_components")) Is Nothing Then

    If Range("nb_components") = 0 Then
        Range(Rows(str_line), Rows(fin_line)).Hidden = True
    Else
        Range(Rows(str_line), Rows(fin_line)).Hidden = True
        Range(Rows(str_line), Rows(str_line + Range("nb_components").value - 1)).Hidden = False
    End If

End If


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L22")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("L22")
        Case "enhanced":
        Range("AO57:AO1056").value = " "
        variante = Array(Chr(160), "Normal", "Increased", "High")
        With Range("AO57:AO1056").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(variante, ",")
            .IgnoreBlank = False
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
        
        
        Case "standard":
        Range("AO57:AO1056").value = " "
        variante = Array(Chr(160), "Low", "Normal", "Increased", "High")
        
        With Range("AO57:AO1056").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(variante, ",")
            .IgnoreBlank = False
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
        
        Case "small entity":
        Range("AO57:AO1056").value = " "
        variante = Array(Chr(160), "Low", "Normal", "Increased", "High")
        
        
        With Range("AO57:AO1056").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(variante, ",")
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
        End With
        Case Else: Range("AO57:AO1056").value = " "
        With Range("AO57:AO1056").Validation
            .Delete
        End With
    End Select
    Me.Protect Password:="test", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
End If

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: You unprotect the sheet unconditionally at the top of the routine but you protect it inside the `If`-Block. Move the `Unprotect` command inside the `If`-Block so that the sheet is only unprotected if you really change something.

Comment: @FunThomas i edited the question, and put all the code. As you can see i have several for and if blocks. Should i put the Unprotect and protect inside every block?

Comment: Up to you, I don't mind. You can also keep the unprotect unconditional at the top and move the protect at the very end. However you do it, just ensure that if you unprotect the sheet, protect it at the end.

Comment: Know that you can actually run a macro on a protected sheet using the `UserInterfaceOnly` option. The only catch is: the option will decay once you close the file. So a protected sheet with `UserInterfaceOnly` set `True` (which would allow macro execution on a protected sheet) once closed will set said option to `False` (which would not allow any edit made via macro). The solution is to apply the protection once the file is opened, most likely in the `Workbook_Open` routine since applying it during each macro would be tedious and pointlessly demanding.

Comment: Your code protects the sheet only for the case of `Target` being `Range("L22")`. So, you should move the line `Me.Protect Password:="test", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True` just above `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`. You can also previously check if the sheet is protected `If Not Me.ProtectContents then` and protect it... And `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` in your code context does not look so appropriate, as stated above.

Comment: If i put the 'Me.Protect Password:="test", UserInterfaceOnly:=True', before '(Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic)' , i am receiveing an error at '.Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(variante, ",")' with the description 'Run time error 1004. Application-defined or object-defined error' @FaneDuru

Comment: The respective error on the respective code line has nothing to do with the recommended code line moving... Your event unprotect the sheet on  its first code line and if you want the sheet to be protected next time, you must protect it at the code end.